# Generate report from visitor counter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a visitor counter, the table looks like this:

```
  id | country_code |       datetime         | Browser | ...
 ---------------------------------------------------------
  1  |    FR        |   2014-06-20 05:00:28  | FireFox |
  2  |    US        |   2014-06-20 05:00:28  | Chrome  |
  3  |    ZW        |   2014-06-20 05:00:28  | IE      |
```

I want to count how many visitor I had (for example) in an hour at a certain day.
The query looks like this:

```
SELECT HOUR(datetime), COUNT(*) as hits 
FROM counter_table WHERE datetime >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY HOUR(datetime) WITH ROLLUP
```

No problem with this query. 
But I also want count how many visitors I got from a certain country.

I tried everything like `GROUP BY HOUR(datetime), country_code WITH ROLLUP` (I do not need a hourly ROLLUP for the country, I need hourly ROLLUP for hits) or JOIN queries but I can't find a good solution.

The best thing I could come up with was something like this:

```
SUM(IF(country_code = "AF", 1,0)) AS Afghanistan,
...
SUM(IF(country_code = "ZW", 1,0)) AS Zimbabwe
```

But the problem is that there are almost 400 countries in the world. I am not sure if such a long query like above would be good for performance. Unfortunately performance is very important in this case because the table is huge. But otherwise this solution provides exactly what I want.

Maybe there is another database better than MySQL for this kind of problem?

Comment: Are you really looking for a report with 400 columns? If not, what would your ideal result actually look like?

Comment: It would be awesome if I could cover all countries in the report. But I don't think you can do it with resonable performance. So only top 10 countries would be also good.

Comment: can't you do "SELECT country_code, HOUR(datetime), COUNT(*) FROM counter_table ... GROUP BY country_code, HOUR(datetime)" to get what you want?

Comment: This does theoretically work. But for `country_code` I don't need GROUP BY hourly. This way I have an enormous amount of arrays to go through to get the ROLLUP result.

Comment: No matter what db you use you`ll have to use a similar conditional logic if you want operations for each country code.But try it first.

Comment: @yoshi can you write down the result what you are expecting?

Comment: What planet are you on? On my planet, there are approximately 200 countries.